# Xcode push notification certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have update provision profile (added new users). Generated new provision and set to Xcode. But then I don't receive push notification and get error code 8, meaning wrong certificates.

Do I need to update push certificates?

UPD: I use production environment. I just wondering do I need to update push notification certificate when update provision profile or they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html), **error code 8 means invalid device token**.

It happens most commonly when you use a test device token against Apple APNS production server or vice-versa. When you build your iOS app you have development and production profiles, the device token will be different based on which profile you chose!

**EDIT :** Post OP update - Provisioning profile & push notification are related things. For push Notification, open the provisioning portal and then go to App IDs section. Find your app and then there are two options for configuring the Push Notification, one for Development and another for production. If your app is under testing and development, use development and configure that and in return you will get the certificate. which will be placed on the server who will send push notifications.

Then, to regenerate the provisioning profiles, go to the provisioning profiles modify them and then re-download. You will get Push Notification Enabled Provisioning profiles.